# CasperJS and 'Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL' error

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, integration-testing, casperjs

I have simple page with javascript which validates email written in input:

**email.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Email validation</title>
        <script src="email.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span style="padding: 5px;">
            <input type="text" id="email-input" placeholder="Email..."></input>
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

**email.js:**

```
var checkEmail = function() {
    var regexp = /BIG_REGEX/;
    var email = document.getElementById('email-input').value;
    if (email === '') 
        removeFrame();
    else if (regexp.test(email))
        drawFrame('green');
    else
        drawFrame('red');
};

var removeFrame = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('email-input');
    input.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = input.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor;
};

var drawFrame = function(color) {
    var input = document.getElementById('email-input');
    input.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = color;
};


window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('email-input').onkeyup = checkEmail;
};
```

I want to test validation functionality using CasperJS. Here is my test case:

**test/validator.test.js:**

```
var fillEmail = function(browser, email) {
    browser.sendKeys('#email-input', email, {reset: true});
};

var getValidation = function(browser) {
    var color = browser.evaluate(function () {
        return document.getElementById('email-input').parentNode.style.backgroundColor;
    });
    return color;
};

var validate = function(browser, email) {
    fillEmail(browser, email);
    return getValidation(browser);
};

casper.test.begin('Validation testing', function suite(test) {
    casper.start('http://localhost:8000/email.html', function() {
        test.assertEquals(validate(this, 'uskovm@gmail.com'), 'green', 'uskovm@gmail.com');
        test.assertEquals(validate(this, 'vnbgfjbndkjnv'), 'red', 'vnbgfjbndkjnv');
    }).run(function() {
        test.done();
    });

});
```

But when I run tests using `casperjs test test/validator.test.js`, there is always error after information about tests:

`Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/home/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

What's wrong?

PhantomJS version: 1.9.8

Comment: Have you narrowed it down which line causes this? If not, add some console.log and try to narrow it down to one line.

Comment: @ArtjomB. This line is printed when test passing is done (after `PASS 2 tests executed in 2.693s, 2 passed...`)

Comment: This is because of some change that was introduced in PhantomJS 1.9.8 and there is a [CasperJS issue](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/1068) about it. So [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608391/using-phantomjs-to-embed-all-images-of-a-webpage) might be related, but since this error comes up when the script finished, I don't see what can be done.

Comment: Ok, this happens when the script exits. I don't see that anything can be done for CasperJS to remove those warnings. I created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12697) for the PhantomJS problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Recent PhantomJS (1.9.8) introduced this error message. It doesn't cause any real issue, other than confusing log lines when quiting PhantomJS.

It is fixed in unreleased 1.9 branch:
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/12720

Comment: This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26688062/789683) has a workaround for the issue

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in  phantomjs version 1.9

"`phantomjs": "^1.9.9"`

for casperJs

```
casperjs --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 test  run.js
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same error, so I tried updating to `phantomjs 1.9.9` (from `1.9.8`). However, I was getting an install error when trying to install `1.9.9`, so I down rev-ed to `phantomjs 1.9.7`, and that fixed this error for me. So, it seems like this is an issue introduced in `phantomjs 1.9.8`.

Comment: Thank you !
If someone needs previous exe files: https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Hey there are several workarounds to try and get around this by exiting phantom in a different way such as

```
   casperjs --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 test  run.js
```

WHICH DOSE NOT HELP and

```
setTimeout(function(){
    phantom.exit();
}, 0);
```

instead of

```
this.exit();
```

Nothing has worked!!!

I tried several different versions of PhantomJS.
My output comes in as JSON and after many hours of failed attempts of JSON.parse(stdout)I had to give up. I figured 'F' it I'm just going to handle the 'F'ing error.

so simple before i exit i

```
this.echo(',{"error":"');
```

and After I send

```
this.echo('"}]');
```

When i get my results back i simply replace all the line breaks and ignore the error

```
stdout = stdout.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '');
```

Side note: this problem was tried to be fixed with phantom 1.9.9 but instead the focussed on building phantom 2.0 which is not compatible with CasperJS