# Log GET requests triggered by clicks using PhantomJS

Tags: dom, get, click, window, phantomjs

I've got a simple web app (a pronunciation guide) which display a list of terms as links. When the user clicks on one, it triggers an audio player to play the pronunciation.

So there is a click event which triggers a GET request to get the audio file which is then loaded by the player and played.

I'd like log all the GET requests, to see if all are successful. I'm trying to use PhantomJS to do so. I cobbled this together:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address = "http://d-college.cengage.com/demos/pronuncation_guide/index.html"


    page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
        console.log('requested: ' + JSON.stringify(req, undefined, 4));
    };

    page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
        console.log('received: ' + JSON.stringify(res, undefined, 4));
    };

    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        }

        page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
        page.evaluate(function() {
                $("a").click();
            });
        phantom.exit()
     });
    });
```

This does successfully log all the assets on page load, as well as the included jquery. But then I get:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL file://clicklog.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

I think this isn't really an error per se (see: [CasperJS and 'Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670696/casperjs-and-unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url-error)) nor do I believe that its causing the program to barf.

But are the clicks happening? Why aren't the resulting GET requests being logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those printed *Unsafe...* lines is a bug that was introduced in 1.9.8 and only happens during `phantom.exit()`. It doesn't interfere with the rest of the script.

You probably aren't seeing those requests, because you exit too early. My understanding is that the *Unsafe...* lines are printed when there is still something executed when you exit. This fits into your case when you click a link and immediately exit. You should let the page at least send the request by delaying the `exit` with `setTimeout`:

```
page.evaluate(...);
setTimeout(function(){
    phantom.exit();
}, 1000);
```