# Unsafe javascript attempt to access frame when installing casperjs through npm windows

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I have installed casperjs and phantomjs on my windows machina via npm. However I get this issue.

```
C:\>casperjs sample.js

C:\>Unable to open file: sample.js
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame
with URL file:///C:/Users/vini/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js.
Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Comment: Hello, it is best to include the actual text of errors or code as it is searchable and is easier for people helping you to copy and paste if they need to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known issue with CasperJS and the 1.9.8 version of PhantomJS. It doesn't do anything and the errors are only printed during exit. They don't interfere with your script. There is a workaround and it was merged into master branch on GitHub, but it is not available as a release of CasperJS yet (latest is 1.1-beta3).

The **easiest way** to solve this is to downgrade to PhantomJS 1.9.7. Since you're using NPM it is easily done with

```
npm -g install phantomjs@1.9.7-15
```

The PhantomJS versions match with the NPM phantomjs package versions up until 1.9.7, then everything breaks. You can check the versions with `npm show phantomjs`.

If you downgrade to version 1.9.7, you will have to run with the `--ssl-protocol=any` commandline option for sites that request https resources. The reason is shown in my answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26419531/1816580)

The **proper way** to solve this is to [install a new version from git](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-from-git). This will enable you to not only use PhantomJS 1.9.8 without the additional error lines, but also PhantomJS 2 which would not be possible with CasperJS 1.1-beta3.

References:
[GitHub issue #1068](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/1068)
[Workaround for CasperJS #1139](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/pull/1139)
[PhantomJS issue on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608391/using-phantomjs-to-embed-all-images-of-a-webpage-produces-warnings-but-works)

Comment: would this be solved if i install a previous version of phantomjs?

Comment: how do i downgrade the version could you pls help with that

Comment: This answer is gold, for anyone wondering this is still relevant as of today with npm casperjs and phantomjs

Comment: I'm using the grunt plugin phantomcss where the same error occured. I downgraded the phantomjs node module but - the error doesn't occure anymore but the contents which I wanted to screenshot doesn't load anyway. So how to allow CORS in pahntomjs or casperjs? Within the plugin's js file I set `pageSettings: {
    webSecurityEnabled: false
  },
  sslProtocol: 'any'` within casper.create but it didn't change anything

Comment: @user2718671 I have no experience with grunt or phantomcss. You could just ask a new question if you haven't done already.

Answer (score 0):

Use
"`phantomjs": "^1.9.9"`
And for caseperJs

```
casperjs --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 test  run.js
```