# Which version of CasperJS is working well with PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, browser, phantomjs, version, casperjs

But the cases often occurred when each of us who new to CasperJS or Phantom.... they start to combine both latest version and try to execute the tutorial (from the old-out-dated resource) >> Result is... error on many parts.

Thus, to overcome this matter.
I wish there's some notes about both versions that workings well side-by-side.
For instance

**casperJS 1.0.4 and phantomJS 1.8.2**  >> not a good choice, 
because function of `this.getElementsInfo()` will not working well inside the code.

Comment: did you see http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/upgrading/1.1.html? each version of casper should have recommended versions of phantom to use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- CasperJS 1.1-beta3 works well with PhantomJS 1.9.0 - 1.9.8.
- [Newest CasperJS from git](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-from-git) works well with PhantomJS 1.9.0 - 2.0.0.
- [Avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29326956/1816580) PhantomJS 1.9.8 if you need clean output.
- I recommend to have multiple versions installed: 2.0.0, 1.9.8 and 1.9.7 in parallel as different executables. You can then use `set PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=myphantomjs` on windows or `export PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=myphantomjs` on linux to change between them easily just before calling CasperJS. I tend to have the executables phantomjs200, phantomjs198 and phantomjs197 lying around.

Comment: This answer is not given in any "official" capacity, but is only based on some past experience.